# Have two decks of cards ever been shuffled in the same order?

Tags: statistics, gambling

Assuming that all the shuffles are truly random shuffles, and that approximately 1 trillion shuffles have been shuffled in the history of the world. What are the odds that a shuffle has come up with the same order twice?

I think the answer is: $$
(52!-1)(52!-2)(52!-3)\cdots(52!-n)
/ (52!)^n ,
$$
where $n = 10^{12}$

How do I compute this?

Comment: A few nitpicks.  "Odds" and "Probability" are related concepts but have different definitions and meanings.  The probability of rolling a $6$ on a fair six-sided die is $\frac{1}{6}$.  The *odds* on the other hand are $1:5$.  If you want to talk about probabilities, then use the word probability... never "odds" as it does not mean the same thing.  Next, the notation $n\frac{k}{~}$ for [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) makes your expression much easier to write as $\dfrac{(52!-1)\frac{n}{~}}{(52!)^n}$.

Comment: Next, "...has come up with the same order twice..." is a bit ambiguous.  Surely you mean "at least one shuffle has come up with the same order at least twice" rather than an interpretation with the word "exactly" in its place somewhere.  Finally, your attempt looks like you are actually calculating that *no* shuffle has ever been repeated rather than the event you seem to be describing.

Comment: All of this being said... your answer is very close, but you subtracted $1$ for no reason from each of the terms in the numerator.  The *probability* $\dfrac{(52!)\frac{n}{~}}{(52!)^n}$ is the probability that *no* shuffle has been repeated within $n$ perfectly random shuffles and subtracting this away from $1$ gives the value you are supposedly interested in.  As for approximating this value, recall that $n\frac{k}{~}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ and use [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Thank you for your notes! I had not heard of falling factorials or Stirling's Approximation. That helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your expression is actually about no repeats in $10^{12} + 1$ trials, but it doesn't matter very much. Write $n = 10^{12}$. Note that your probability is certainly less than 1, and we can find a rather coarse lower bound for it by
$$
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n} 52! - i}{(52!)^{n}} \geq \frac{(52! - n)^{n}}{(52!)^n} \approx 1 - 1.2398 \times 10^{-44}.
$$
Here we used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=scientific+notation+1+-+exp(10%5E12*(log(52!+-+10%5E12)+-+log(52!))) in the last step. This means that under your assumptions, there almost certainly has not been a shuffle resulting in the same order yet.

Comment: Thank you, that answers what I was asking. I could not intuitively answer it. If I may ask a follow up question.How many decks would have to be shuffled for there to be a 50% chance of the same shuffle twice?

Comment: The wikipedia page *https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem* gives you a nice formula to estimate this number.

Comment: Thank you thibo, I put according to that I calculated: $\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + 2 \times ln(2) \times 52!} \approx 10^{34}$

Comment: @ljump12 yeah, Wolfram gives $\sqrt{2\times52!\times\ln(2)} \approx 1.0574× 10^{34}$